# How to insert datepicker and timepicker in sqlite database in android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

How to store Date with day and Time with Minutes ,I want to insert selected Date and selected Time in Database.

```
public class FutureSms extends AppCompatActivity {
DbHelper db;
EditText name,mob,msg;
DatePicker dp;
TimePicker tp;
Button b1;
Button b2;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_future_sms);

    db = new DbHelper(this);
    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    dp = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.date);
    tp = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.time);
    mob = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.mobnumber);
    msg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.msg);
     b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
     b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.view);
    AddData();
}
public  void  AddData()
{
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {



            boolean isInserted = db.insertData(
                    name.getText().toString(),
                    dp.getDayOfMonth();
                    tp.getCurrentHour();
                    mob.getText().toString(),
                    msg.getText().toString());
            if(isInserted == true)
                Toast.makeText(FutureSms.this,"Data Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(FutureSms.this,"Data not Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}}
```

This is xml for layout of view.

```
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Select a time to send Message"
    android:textColor="#3B5998"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

        <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/pickerdate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TimePicker
            android:id="@+id/pickertime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/setalarm"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Set Alarm"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

DbHealper(this code contain to store database for insertion , deletion ,updation and view )

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public  static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Alert.db";
public  static final String TABLE_NAME = "MessageAlert";
public  static final String COL = "ID" ;
public  static final String COL_1 = "NAME";
public  static final String COL_2 = "DATE";
public  static final String COL_3 = "TIME";
public  static final String COL_4= "MOBILE";
public  static final String COL_5 = "MESSAGE";

public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("create table" + TABLE_NAME + "( ID INTEGER PRIMERY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,NAME TEXT,DATE TEXT,TIME TEXT,MOBILE TEXT,MESSAGE TEXT } " );

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("IF DROP TABLE EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);

}

public boolean insertData(String name,String date,String time,String mobile,String message) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_1,name);
    contentValues.put(COL_2,date);
    contentValues.put(COL_3,time);
    contentValues.put(COL_4,mobile);
    contentValues.put(COL_5,message);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null ,contentValues);
    if(result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

public Integer deleteData (String id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "ID = ?",new String[] {id});
}



public Cursor getAllData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME,null);
    return res;
}

public boolean updateData(String id,String name,String date,String time,String mobile,String message) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL,id);
    contentValues.put(COL_1,name);
    contentValues.put(COL_2,date);
    contentValues.put(COL_3,time);
    contentValues.put(COL_4,mobile);
    contentValues.put(COL_5,message);
    db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "ID = ?",new String[] { id });
    return true;
}}
```

Comment: So what is the problem? You get exception?

Answer (score 1):

`Date` in Java is just amount of milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00.000 GMT. So you can convert it back and forth to long variable. 
`Date.getTime()` to get `long` value of date (It's UNIX TimeStamp in milliseconds). And use `new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())` to create your `Date` object back. So in the end you simply need to store one long value in your database.